# Integrate gives wrong result for simple function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug introduced in 5.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.3**

---

It looks like this.

```
NIntegrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
22.7929
Integrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
0
```

Zero result is wrong since the denominator is nonsingular and always positive. Why is this or just a bug?

I noticed this more than three years ago (Version 9) and found it persisting till Version 11.2.

Comment: The reason for the exception is not a pole (which is absent in the region of integration) but a discontinuity in the indefinite integral. A simplified case is $\int \frac{1}{\sin (x)+2} \, dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$. Dealing correctly with discontinuous antiderivatives has been widely discussed in this forum.

Answer (score 13):

Using

```
Integrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From help

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica sees a simple pole in the integrand. That is why it says

```
 Integrate[1/(2+Sin[x+y]),{x,0,2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I actually do not see the pole myself. Since $\sin()$  can only be between $-1\dots1$, so integrand denominator can't be zero. But Mathematica says there is a pole there! Needs more investigation to find why Mathematica wants $y$ to be only between $-\pi\dots\pi$.

**Update**

---

I had to go back to version 2.2 to get Mathematica to give the same result as Integrate without using any options.  (I could not test this on version 5 and 6 at this time)

Here is screen shot from version 2.2 on windows XP

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Shifting either or both intervals to {-Pi, Pi} works. `Integrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]`, `Integrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]`, and `Integrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]` each evaluates to `(4*Pi^2)/Sqrt[3]`.

Comment: Nasser, Bob, please see my comment to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

On new `Mathematica 11.3`:

```
Integrate[1/(2 + Sin[x + y]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> $$\frac{4 \pi ^2}{\sqrt{3}}$$